# How to click another tab, while prompt box is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a prompt box for users to be able to input a link, but if they don't already have the link to paste, they'll have to close the box, because it wont let them click any other tab, then go get the link, then hit the button to bring back up the prompt box.

Is there a way to let users click another tab WITHOUT having to close the prompt box?

```
$('.stillWrong').on('click', function(){ 
  $('.correctTab').hide(); 

  var theTab = prompt('Paste your tab link here.');
  $('.tabs-results').empty(); 

  $('.tabs-results').html('<iframe src="' + theTab + '"' + 'width="850" + height="975" frameborder="0"' + 'allowtransparency="true" scrolling="yes" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts">' + '</iframe>'); })
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Some code can help :)

Comment: There is no way to do this using javascript's native `prompt` method, however you could build a custom prompt box that would allow that behavior using an html form and some javascript and CSS to make it "pop" above the the rest of the page.

Comment: if you are using `prompt()` then there is not much you can do, it is handled by the browser, instead you could try a JS modal window, so you have more control over it, e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: `code` $('.stillWrong').on('click', function(){
  
        $('.correctTab').hide();

        var theTab = prompt('Paste your tab link here.');
        
        $('.tabs-results').empty();
        $('.tabs-results').html('<iframe src="' + theTab + '"' 
        + 'width="850" + height="975" frameborder="0"' 
        + 'allowtransparency="true" scrolling="yes" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts">' + '</iframe>');
        });

Comment: Im sorry, but Im new & trying to add my code. Not sure how to do it so it's easy to read.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answers!! Im learning how to use CSS to make the form hover, aka 'pop' up, above the page.